# java.lang.NullPointerException FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-876799952849-1]

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Please do read this my question completely before marking it as duplicate cz i have already searched thouroughly for this case.I am currently working on an android app that remotely controls your android device via a website.Currently this exception is given when i am trying to send a command to start the audio recorder .I have made a class named audiorecorder.java whose object is created when the message "startrecorder" arrives from the server side.This message is actually  compared in gcmintent service.java .I am pasting the code snippet as well as the logcat.Kindly help me because this error is being given not only in audiorecorder feature's acse but in other cases as well like for taking a scrrenshot or taking a picture from camera.
Thanx in advance.

Audiorecorder.java

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

import android.app.Activity;

public class AudioRecorder extends Activity {
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    public String path;

    public void onCreate(String path) {
        this.path = sanitizePath(path);
    }

    private String sanitizePath(String path) {
        if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = "/" + path;
        }
        if (!path.contains(".")) {
            path += ".3gp";
        }
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + path;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
                    + ".");
        }

        // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
        File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
        }

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }

    public void playrecording(String path) throws IOException {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setVolume(10, 10);
    }

}   





Gcmintentservice.java --->
 else if(message.equalsIgnoreCase ("startrecorder")){

            AudioRecorder a = new AudioRecorder();
            try {
                a.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }




Logcat:

    11-23 11:36:11.338: D/dalvikvm(2313): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 51% free 2687K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 362ms
    11-23 11:36:11.438: D/dalvikvm(2313): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 2688K/5379K, external 0K/512K, paused 88ms
    11-23 11:36:18.685: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2313): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
    11-23 11:36:18.695: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2313): GCM IntentService class: com.androidhive.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService
    11-23 11:36:18.695: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2313): Acquiring wakelock
    11-23 11:36:18.735: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2313): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-876799952849-1
    11-23 11:36:18.755: I/GCMIntentService(2313): Received message
    11-23 11:36:18.775: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2313): Releasing wakelock
    11-23 11:36:18.775: W/dalvikvm(2313): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-876799952849-1]
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:205)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at java.io.File.init(File.java:189)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:139)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AudioRecorder.start(AudioRecorder.java:39)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:128)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    11-23 11:36:18.785: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: How do you initialize `path`?

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong :

```
public String path;

public void onCreate(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
}
```

This `orCreate` doesn't have the signature of the [noCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method of `Activity`, so it is not executed when you start the activity. Therefore `path` remains null, leading to your `NullPointerException` at `File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();`.

If you wish to pass a `path` variable to your activity, you should put it in the Intent that starts the activity.

Comment: what do i need to change then?How can i add noCreate method's signature?

Comment: @user3191197 You need to properly start the `AudioRecorder` activity. `AudioRecorder a = new AudioRecorder();` is not how you create/start an activity.

Comment: I replaced  AudioRecorder a = new AudioRecorder(); with    Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setClass(this, AudioRecorder.class);
         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(i); It now gives an exception as wrriten :Activity not found .11-23 15:11:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(789): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidhive.pushnotifications/com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AudioRecorder}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @GaneshJha Well, have you declared this activity in your manifest?

Comment: Yeah i have added the activity in manifest now.But now it is not giving any exception neither the recorder is opening.The only thing that happens is on recieving the startrecorder message a black screen opens up.

Comment: @GaneshJha I guess the activity is opened and you didn't configure any view for it, so the default is probably a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't given wake lock permissions in your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: It still force closes the app .

Comment: still same error in logcat or this time its different?

Comment: same error.11-23 14:43:36.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2601): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-876799952849-1]
11-23 14:43:36.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2601): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 14:43:36.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2601):  at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:205)
11-23 14:43:36.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2601):  at java.io.File.init(File.java:189)
11-23 14:43:36.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2601):  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:139)
11-23 14:43:36.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2601):  at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AudioRecorder.start(AudioRecorder.java:39)

Comment: hmmm, there seems to be some problem witth your recorder, you can try setting default values to setAudioEncoder and others, maybe it will help i ain't sure